# Empty NSMutableArray read from plist becomes immutable object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Write an empty NSMutableArray to disk, then read it back, it becomes an immutable object.
But, if the NSMutableArray is not empty, it won't. How to explain that?
here are the codes:

```
NSMutableArray *testItems1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *testList1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:testItems1, @"list_items", @"list1", @"list_name", nil];

NSMutableArray *testItems2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"item11", @"item22", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *testList2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:testItems2, @"list_items", @"list2", @"list_name", nil];

NSMutableArray *testLists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:testList1, testList2, nil];

[testLists writeToFile:@"/tmp/testLists" atomically:YES];

NSMutableArray *testReadLists = [NSMutableArray array];
[testReadLists setArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/testLists"]];
NSMutableDictionary *testReadList = [testReadLists objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray *testReadItems = [testReadList objectForKey:@"list_items"];
[testReadItems addObject:@"item3"]; // Crashes here: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'"
```

Comment: Write the data as JSON.  Read back with NSJSONSerialization, specifying the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.

Comment: FYI - your path to `/tmp` is only going to be valid in the Simulator or maybe a jailbroken iOS device. DO NOT use such a path in "real" code.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines of code:

```
NSMutableArray *testReadLists = [NSMutableArray array];
[testReadLists setArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/testLists"]];
```

give you a mutable array of immutable objects. You can add and remove objects from `testReadLists` but everything you get from this array (originally loaded from the plist) will be immutable.

Update - I was about to post info about the solution but the answer by Vivek describes what I was going to say.

Comment: `[[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/testLists"] mutableCopy]` is easier

Comment: Why not just `[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/testLists"];`?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this myself, but you probably want to first read the plist into an NSData, and then get the actual array by doing `+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]`, specifying `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` in the options argument (apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/propertyListWithData%3aoptions%3aformat%3aerror%3a))

Note this should give you a full hierarchy of mutable containers (an NSMutableArray containing NSMutableDictionaries, and so on). If all you want is an NSMutableArray at one particular level in the hierarchy, then the other posted solution/comments would probably be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: What about [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file] ? I changed to this and it works now

Comment: I have tested 3 levels(NSMutableDictionary contains NSMutableDictionary contains NSMutableArray) plist data read with [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file]. The most inside NSMutableArray is mutable. [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:] is also give a full hierarchy of mutable containers, and it's more simple than read to NSData and use +[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]

Answer (score 0):

Objects read straight from property lists are *always* immutable. You might create a mutable object from them, but the objects themselves are immutable. These lines are the problem:

```
NSMutableDictionary *testReadList = [testReadLists objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray *testReadItems = [testReadList objectForKey:@"list_items"];
```

`testReadList` is the first object in the mutable array `testReadLists`, but that object itself is still immutable despite the fact that the declared type of `testReadList` is `NSMutable*`. Likewise, the object you get back from the `objectForKey:` call is an instance of `NSArray` even though you're assigning it to `testReadItems`, which is declared as `NSMutableArray*`. You can avoid the problem by simply making a mutable copy before you add new items:

```
NSMutableArray *testReadItems = [[testReadList objectForKey:@"list_items"] mutableCopy];
```